# How to get the range of analytical solution of inequalities?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

Is there a way to get the range of analytical solution of inequalities? Such as:

```mathematica
Reduce[x + 2 y + 3 c + 4 d == 3/2 && x + y + c + d == 2 && x >= 2 && 
  y < 2 && c < 3 && d > 5, {x, y, c, d}]
```

The Mathematica outputs:

```mathematica
((15/4 < x <= 31/2 && 1/2 (19 - 4 x) < y < 2 && 
     c == 1/2 (13 - 6 x - 4 y)) || (x > 31/2 && 
     1/4 (7 - 6 x) < y < 2 && c == 1/2 (13 - 6 x - 4 y))) && 
 d == 1/8 (3 - 6 c - 2 x - 4 y)
```

I think the result can be further narrowed down, knowing the **x** range, know **y**, then know **z**, then know **t**.

After finding the analytical solution, how to narrow all the ranges of the variables?

Comment: It seems correct to me. In what form would you like the solution?

Comment: Why is this not an analytical solution?

Comment: @MichaelE2 a=[0,5]

Comment: @DanielHuber a=[0,5]

Comment: Perhaps `Reduce[5 == a + b && b > 0 && a < 8, {a}, {b}]` is what you seek, unless you want it converted to interval notation. (I don't think your system implies $a \ge 0$.)

Comment: @MichaelE2  Yes. You are right!

Comment: @MichaelE2  Why reduce can find the result but Solve gives other form of the result?

Comment: `Solve` solves for the value(s) of the requested variable(s). It is principally an equation solver, and it not an inequality solver. It will use inequalities as constraints on the solution(s). If you execute `Solve[5 == a + b && b > 0 && a < 8, {a}, {b}]`, you will see that there exists an error message warning about this in a way, and advising the use of `Reduce[]`

Comment: @MichaelE2  I modified my question to upgrade the difficulty. Hope you can check that.

Comment: Again, you need to clarify the form of answer you seek.  You have three equations and some constraints for four variables.  The form of solution I would expect are formulas for three of the variables and an interval for the fourth variable, which is what you get. -- A side note: When possible avoid floating-point numbers like `-2.5` and `-1.5` in exact solvers like `Reduce[]` or `Solve[]`. They introduce round-off errors in the algorithms, and the errors sometimes cause problems with the solution. Use `-5/2` instead of `-2.5` and `-3/2` instead of `-1.5`.

Comment: @MichaelE2  I updated my queation again. Hope you can check it.

Comment: It appears you want the "bounding box," not the solution set. `Reduce[system, {x, y, c, d}]` gave you the range on the first variable `x`. Likewise `Reduce[system, {y, x, c, d}]` will give you the range on the first variable `y`.  And so on. Off hand I don't know an easier way to do that for a four+ variable system, but it's likely there is one for linear systems. Maybe someone else will know.

Comment: Perhaps you can try something like `FunctionRange[{y, constraints}, {x, c, d}, y]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Your way at least works well.

Comment: Yoclaim about the result of `Reduce` does not correspond to reality. In 13.3.1.0 on Windows 10 `Reduce[x + 2 y + 3 c + 4 d == 3/2 && x + y + c + d == 2 && x >= 2 && 
  y < 2 && c < 3 && d > 5, {x, y, c, d}]` produces `((15/4<x<=31/2&&1/2 (19-4 x)<y<2&&c==1/2 (13-6 x-4 y))||(x>31/2&&1/4 (7-6 x)<y<2&&c==1/2 (13-6 x-4 y)))&&d==1/8 (3-6 c-2 x-4 y)`, not `(15/4 < x <= 31/2 && 1/2 (19 - 4 x) < y < 2 && 
     c == 1/2 (13 - 6 x - 4 y)) || (x > 31/2 && 
     1/4 (7 - 6 x) < y < 2 && c == 1/2 (13 - 6 x - 4 y))) && 
 d == 1/8 (3 - 6 c - 2 x - 4 y)`.

Comment: @user64494  The two results you posted is the same? What's the diffierent?

Comment: @Y.zeng: You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Making use of linear optimization, this can be done as follows (Unfortunately, the `Backsubstitution->True` option does not work here.).

```
Minimize[{y,    x + 2 y + 3 c + 4 d == 3/2 && x + y + c + d == 2 && x >= 2 &&     y < 2 && c < 3 && d > 5}, {x, y, c, d}]
```

> Minimize::wksol: Warning: there is no minimum in the region in which the objective function is defined and the constraints are satisfied; returning a result on the boundary.`{-\[Infinity], {x -> Indeterminate, y -> Indeterminate,  c -> Indeterminate, d -> Indeterminate}}`

```
Maximize[{y,  x + 2 y + 3 c + 4 d == 3/2 && x + y + c + d == 2 && x >= 2 &&  y < 2 && c < 3 && d > 5}, {x, y, c, d}]
```

> Maximize::wksol: Warning: there is no maximum in the region in which the objective function is defined and the constraints are satisfied; a result on the boundary will be returned.`{2, {x -> 15/4, y -> 2, c -> -(35/4), d -> 0}}`

Therefore, `y < 2`, Similarly, the range of `c` is `c < 3`. All that ranges can be obtained through `Table` over `{x,y,c,d}`.

Edit.  `x + 2 y + 3 c + 4 d == 3/2 && x + y + c + d == 2 && x >= 2 &&     y < 2 && c < 3 && d > 5` instead of `((15/4 < x <= 31/2 && 1/2 (19 - 4 x) < y < 2 &&  c == 1/2 (13 - 6 x - 4 y)) || (x > 31/2 &&  1/4 (7 - 6 x) < y < 2 && c == 1/2 (13 - 6 x - 4 y))) &&  d == 1/8 (3 - 6 c - 2 x - 4 y)`.